# wait for db operation on another thread

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce, windows-phone

i am using Linq to sql for database operations in my WP8 Project. Is there a common way to perform a wait operation while another thread is performing operations on that database? Sometimes i get an unhandled exception that will terminate the App, because there are Operations pending.

Answer (score 2):

Use a locking mechanism.

First, create an object in your class:

```
private object syncRoot = new object();
```

Then, enclose all critical sections of the code inside of a `lock` block:

```
lock (this.syncRoot)
{
    // This section of code will be executed by only one thread at a time
}
```

All the code inside of a `lock` block will be executed by only one thread at a time. If two threads try to execute it, one of them will automatically wait until the other has exited the block. By wrapping all your database operations inside `lock` blocks, you'll make sure that only one thread at a time can access it.

Comment: hi KooKiz thanks for the quick answer. locking inside async functions is not allowed, wich i use i.e. to update UI elements such as lists. and for that reason accessing the database is very decentralized. But i am gonna give it a try, thank you!

Comment: @ElMarchewko Check this link: [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 6: AsyncLock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx) for a way to lock async blocks.